# replace dots and comma from a QRegExp unicode value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a unicode value which is derived from this kind of validator:

```
# numbers with dots and comma
validator= QtGui.QRegExpValidator(QtCore.QRegExp("^\\d{1,3}(([.]\\d{3})*),(\\d{2})$"))
```

I need to replace all *dots* and *commas* in this value and convert it to int

i've tried to make:

```
# the replace.replace below i used to use in c++
newvalue = int(oldvalue.replace(".","").replace(",",""))
```

but it only works to values like: 1.000.000,000

in values like 0,00 or 500.000,00 i have this error message:

```
The debugged program raised the exception unhandled AttributeError "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'"
```

someone could help me with this replace?
thank you very much!

Comment: Could you put examples of desired inputs and outputs?

Comment: You could put more code because I tried and I had no problems.

Comment: Probably vice versa, 1.000.000,000 cannot pass your validator (due to 3 digits after comma, not two as required) and then None value produces an error, and 0,00 or 500.000,00 work nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

the problem was that in some cases, `oldvalue == None`, so i had that error message.

problem solved with a simple verification:

```
if self.rec1[5] != None:
    newvalue = int(oldvalue.replace(".","").replace(",",""))
```

Comment: change if `self.rec1[5] != None:` to `if not self.rec1[5] :`   :P